# unable to marshal type " " as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation. wsdl schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, wsdl, xjc

I'm writing "Consuming a SOAP web service" from a tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/#initial . And I ran into this problem when sending a message:

```
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "wsdl.Request" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

I used gradle and the same settings as described in https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/#initial